# Natural morphisms between stable unitary, orthogonal, and (compact) symplectic groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, classifying-spaces

I am a physicist knowing a bit of algebraic topology, and trying to answer the following question.
This is perhaps not appropriate as a question on MO, in which case I apologize.
I posted this question on MSE, but haven't received any answer.

Any help will be appreciated, and so will the suggestion of materials to look up for learning these things.

The subgroup inclusions
$$ 
U(N) \hookrightarrow Sp(N):=U(2N) \cap Sp(2N,\mathbb{C}), \quad U(N) \hookrightarrow O(2N)
$$
induce some morphisms
$$
f_1: U(\infty)\to Sp(\infty),  f_2: U(\infty)\to O(\infty).
$$

Are they related by the Bott periodicity isomorphisms $U(\infty) \simeq \Omega^{4}U(\infty)$ and $Sp(\infty) \simeq \Omega^{4} O(\infty)$? That is, is the map
$$
U(\infty) \xrightarrow{\sim} \Omega^{4}U(\infty) \xrightarrow{\Omega^{4}f_{2}} \Omega^{4}O(\infty) \xrightarrow{\sim} Sp(\infty)
$$
homotopic to $f_{1}$?

The motivation for my question is to compute the map $\pi_5[U(\infty)] = \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{2} = \pi_5[Sp(\infty)]$ induced by $f_1$. If the above is true, then using
$$
[S^5, Sp(\infty)] \simeq [\Sigma^4 S^1, Sp(\infty)] \simeq [S^1, \Omega^4 Sp(\infty)] \simeq [S^1, O(\infty)],
$$
one would be able to reduce the problem to computing $\pi_1[U(\infty)] \to \pi_1[O(\infty)]$ induced by $f_2$, which seems to me just as $\mod 2: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.